# Glassfish error message "javax.ejb.EJBException"

Tags: ejb

I have established connection with a database where I retrive some information from it. I have several variables declared and I would like to fill those variables with this database information. The problem is, everything works fine when I retrive information from the database for one of my variables, but when I am trying to retrive one more string, I get the error message "javax.ejb.EJBException".

I am using beans and servlets. The servlet sends some information to the bean, the bean calls for an another class, where database connection is, and it sends some information back to the bean.

I am using Java Netbeans, Glassfish Server and MySQL database.

Do anyone know how I could solve this problem?

EDIT:
I have tried to remove the last retriving from the database, just to be sure that it works, but it doesent. Now the error message comes up every time I try to retrive information.

Answer (score 0):

Can we have some code ? Without that, it's difficult to us for understanding where the error is.

Check your stacktrace in NetBeans, it describes the error and where it is located (where the exception is thrown).